# Azure DevOps release stages is there a limit of how many stages you can have?

Tags: azure-devops, release, stage

Azure DevOps are designed to handle complex workflows, but as with any system, excessively large or complex configurations can lead to performance issues or manageability challenges.

Azure DevOps release stages: Is there a limit of how many stages you can have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), there is a limit of 256 jobs for a stage in Azure Pipelines. However, there is no explicit limit on the number of stages you can have in a release pipeline.

I tried to validate with 110 stages, and it's working.

```
variables:
  - name: stage
    value: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,109,110

stages:
- ${{ each stage in split(variables.stage, ',') }}:
  - stage: stage_${{ stage }}
    jobs:
      - job: job1
        steps:
          - bash: echo test
```

I skipped manually, but you can see stage_110 listed:

[image]